# implode first element in associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have one index array which contain associative array. Like this

```
$arr = array(
            array("id" => 1,"name" => "student1"),
            array("id" => 2,"name" => "student2"),
            array("id" => 3,"name" => "student3"),
        );
```

Now I want output like this

```
1,2,3 // output
```

I have solution for it but I am searching for better way to do that. Here it is

```
$ids = "";
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{
    $ids .= $arr[$i]['id'].",";
}

$ids = rtrim($ids,",");
echo $ids; // output : 1,2,3
```

Is there any better way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative using `array_map()` if you don't have PHP 5.5+:

```
echo implode(',', array_map(function($v) { return $v['id']; }, $arr));
```

#### [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/twTVET)

Answer (score 3):

If you have php version >= 5.5 then try,

```
echo implode(",",array_column($arr,'id'));
```

Comment: Didn't you forget the `glue` parameter ?

Comment: Thanks Nouphal.M but I have php version 5.4.16

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php

    $arr = array(
                array("id" => 1,"name" => "student1"),
                array("id" => 2,"name" => "student2"),
                array("id" => 3,"name" => "student3"),
            );
    $str = "";      
    foreach ($arr as $value)        
    {

        $str=$str.$value["id"].",";
    }
    $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
    echo $str;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arr as $val){
$ids[]=$val['id'];
}
echo implode(($ids),',');
```